# Jenkinsfile Pipeline dynamic environment modification at runtime

Tags: environment-variables, jenkins-pipeline, gitversion

I need to get `GitVersion.exe` variables in my Jenkins pipeline.

The GitVersion [documentation](https://gitversion.readthedocs.io/en/latest/build-server-support/build-server/jenkins/) gives a hint on how to do that. Essentially call `gitversion /output buildserver`.

This call does add the variables to the current step and they are lost once the step completes. I can show this call executes when combining a `set` command in the same bat execution. The second `set` shows the variables are gone from the environment.

```
bat 'nuget install GitVersion.CommandLine -OutputDirectory c:/packages -Version 3.6.5'
bat 'c:/packages/GitVersion.CommandLine.3.6.5/tools/GitVersion.exe /output buildserver && set'
bat 'set'
```

The documentation of GitVersion is aware of that and suggests to use [EnvInject](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/EnvInject+Plugin).
Installing the plugin and executing the same pipeline did not change the result. I read that the Plugin is not made for pipelines so that may have something to do with it.

Pipelines support a syntax for [environment](https://jenkins.io/doc/pipeline/tour/environment/).

Following that syntax I can set static variables at the top of my pipeline like this:

```
environment {
    ASuperVariable = 'MySuperVariable'
}
```

What I need is combining those calls so that I can add run time variables to the Jenkinsfile pupeline.

```
environment {
    bat 'gitversion /output buildserver'
}
```

Now obviously the above call is not even syntax correct. Is there a way to mark a section so that the contained environment changes are available for other steps?

EDIT:
This is still unsolved. At the moment I need to create a batch script and pass the tool into it as an argument. Inside the batch I can call the tool to add to the environment of the batch script and use that wile the batch is running. A Multi line batch in the Jenkins file could be a solution if the process remains the same over all the multiple lines.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure whether you would be able to use scripted pipeline or at least a script block inside declarative. It'd be quite easy doing so:

```
withEnv(['ASuperVariable=MySuperVariable']) {
    echo env.ASuperVariable
}
```

Or when calling a windows cmd script:

```
node('win') {
    withEnv(['ASuperVariable=MySuperVariable']) {
        bat 'echo %ASuperVariable%'
    }
}
```

Comment: Interesting. It looks like it may not solve the dynamic issue. I will try it just to be sure.

Comment: I tried it and I can not get the result I need - maybe I am doing something wrong here. I have a GitVersion.exe which will set environemnt variables. I want to preserve these environment changes across the Process boundary between steps.

Comment: Maybe I got you wrong. So actually the `GitVersion.exe` is setting some environment variables you want to refer to in your Jenkinsfile? Unfortunately I don't think this will be easily possible. Think you'd need to store the environment created by `GitVersion.exe` to some file and parse that file from within your pipeline.